# Classification TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, split, classification, list-comprehension

I am making an id3 classifier using entropy for cost calculation, but when I am splitting categorical attributes I keep getting a TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable, when running the line: child = [x for x in records if x[attr_name] in a_i], in the method: split_categorical

The dataset:

sunny, 85, 85, false, No
sunny, 80, 90, true, No
overcast, 83, 78, false, Yes
rain, 70, 96, false, Yes
rain, 68, 80, false, Yes
rain, 65, 70, true, No
overcast, 64, 65, true, Yes
sunny, 72, 95, false, No
sunny, 69, 70, false, Yes
rain, 75, 80, false, Yes
sunny, 75, 70, true, Yes
overcast, 72, 90, true, Yes
overcast, 81, 75, false, Yes
rain, 71, 80, true, No

full code:

```
import csv
import math
from statistics import median, mode
from collections import Counter
from enum import Enum


class AttrType(Enum):
    cat = 0  # categorical (qualitative) attribute
    num = 1  # numerical (quantitative) attribute
    target = 2  # target label


class NodeType(Enum):
    root = 0
    internal = 1
    leaf = 2


class SplitType(Enum):
    bin = 0  # binary split
    multi = 1  # multi-way split


class Attribute(object):
    def __init__(self, label, type):
        assert type in AttrType
        self.label = label
        self.type = type
        self.stat = None  # holds mean for numerical and mode for categorical attributes


class Splitting(object):
    def __init__(self, attr, infogain, split_type, cond, splits):
        self.attr = attr  # attribute ID (index in ATTR)
        self.infogain = infogain  # information gain if splitting is done on this attribute
        self.split_type = split_type  # one of SplitType
        self.cond = cond  # splitting condition, i.e., values on outgoing edges
        self.splits = splits  # list of training records (IDs) for each slitting condition


class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, id, type, parent_id, children=None, edge_value=None, val=None, split_type=None, split_cond=None):
        self.id = id  # ID (same as the index in DT.model list)
        self.type = type  # one of NodeType
        self.parent_id = parent_id  # ID of parent node (None if root)
        self.children = children  # list of IDs of child nodes
        self.edge_value = edge_value  # the value of the incoming edge (only if not root node)
        self.val = val  # if root or internal node: the attribute that is compared at that node; if leaf node: the target value
        self.split_type = split_type  # one of SplitType
        self.split_cond = split_cond  # splitting condition (median value for binary splits on numerical values; otherwise a list of categorical values (corresponding to child nodes))
        self.infogain = infogain

    def append_child(self, node_id):
        self.children.append(node_id)


# input filename and data format are hard-coded here
INFILE = "data/example.csv"
# attribute labels types (same order as in the file!)
ATTR = [Attribute("Outlook", AttrType.cat), Attribute("Temperature", AttrType.num),
        Attribute("Humidity", AttrType.num), Attribute("Windy", AttrType.cat), Attribute("Play?", AttrType.target)]
IDX_TARGET = len(ATTR) - 1  # index of the target attribute (assuming it's the last)


#main class:
class DT(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None  # training data set (loaded into memory)
        self.model = None  # decision tree model
        self.default_class = None  # default target class

    def __load_data(self):
        with open(INFILE) as csvfile:
            self.data = []
            csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for row in csvreader:
                rec = []
                for i in range(len(ATTR)):
                    val = row[i].strip()
                    # convert numerical attributes
                    if ATTR[i].type == AttrType.num:  # Note that this will break for "?" (missing attribute)
                        val = float(val)
                    rec.append(val)
                self.data.append(rec)
                # self.data.append([element.strip() for element in row])  # strip spaces

    def __entropy(self, records):
        """
        Calculates entropy for a selection of records.

        :param records: Data records (given by indices)
        """
        # TODO          records er en liste med index til hver record
        #Entropy of a list of records associated with a node. 

        dat = {key:self.data[key] for key in records}
        count = Counter([x[4] for x in dat.values()]) #target=4="Play?"
        return sum([(-freq / len(dat)) * math.log(freq / len(dat), 2) for freq in count.values()])
        #return sum([(-freq / len(self.data)) * math.log(freq / len(self.data), 2) for freq in records])
    def split_categorical(self, records, attr_name, values_sets):
        print("Splitting by {}".format(attr_name))
        children = []
        for a_i in values_sets:  # for each subset of possible values\n",
            child = [x for x in records if x[attr_name] in a_i]  
            children.append(child)
            # e.g. if values_sets = [{\"sunny\"}, {\"overcast\", \"rain\"}], and atr_name = \"Outlook\"\n",
            # then, in the 2nd iteration, a_i = {\"overcast\", \"rain\"},\n",
            # so child = list of records for which the value in \"Outlook\" attr is in {\"overcast\", \"rain\"}\n",

            # We also print the entropy for each child\n",
        print("Child condition: {}Size = {}Entropy = {}".format(a_i, len(child), entropy(child)))
        return children
    def split_numeric_binary(self, records, attr_name, splitting_point):
        print("Splitting by {}".format(attr_name))
        children = [[x for x in records if x[attr_name] <= splitting_point],
                   [x for x in records if x[attr_name] > splitting_point]]
        # We also print the entropy for each child
        print("'Less-or-equal-than' child. Size = {}Entropy = {}".format(len(children[0]), entropy(children[0])))
        print("'Greater-than' child. Size = {}Entropy = {}".format(len(children[1]), entropy(children[1])))
        return children
    def infogain(self, parent_records, children_records):
        #param parent_records: list of records associated with the parent node.
        #param children_records: list of lists, each list contains all the records associated with one child.
        entropy_p = entropy(parent_records)
        return entropy_p - sum([(len(child_records) / len(parent_records)) * entropy(child_records)
                                    for child_records in children_records])
    def __find_best_attr(self, attrs, records):
        """
        Finds the attribute with the largest gain.

        :param attrs: Set of attributes
        :param records: Training set (list of record ids)
        :return:
        """
        entropy_p = self.__entropy(records)  # parent's entropy
        splittings = []  # holds the splitting information for each attribute

        for a in attrs:
            assert ATTR[a].type in AttrType
            splits = {}  # record IDs corresponding to each split
            children = []
            # splitting condition depends on the attribute type
            if ATTR[a].type == AttrType.target:  # skip target attribute
                continue
            elif ATTR[a].type == AttrType.cat:  # categorical attribute
                # multi-way split on each possible value
                split_mode = SplitType.multi
                # each possible attr value corresponds to a split (indexed with categorical labels)
                # Note: it's important to consider attr values from the entire training set
                split_cond = set([self.data[idx][a] for idx in range(len(self.data))])

                # TODO collect training records for each split 
                # `splits[val]` holds a list of records for a given split,
                # where `val` is an element of `split_cond`
                #split_categorical og legg til resultat i splits
                children = self.split_categorical(records,a,split_cond)
                for i, val in enumerate(split_cond):
                    splits[val]=children[i] #get records for given split
            elif ATTR[a].type == AttrType.num:  # numerical attribute => binary split on median value
                split_mode = SplitType.bin
                split_cond = self.__median(a)  # (i.e., if less or equal than this value)
                # TODO collect training records for each split (in `splits`)
                children = self.split_numeric_binary(records, a, split_cond)
                for i, val in enumerate(split_cond):
                    splits[val]=children[i]
            # TODO compute gain for attribute a
            infogain = self.infogain(records, children)

            splitting = Splitting(a, infogain, split_mode, split_cond, splits)
            splittings.append(splitting)

        # find best splitting
        best_splitting = sorted(splittings, key=lambda x: x.infogain, reverse=True)[0]
        return best_splitting

    def __add_node(self, parent_id, node_type=NodeType.internal, edge_value=None, val=None, split_type=None,
                   split_cond=None):
        """
        Adds a node to the decision tree.

        :param parent_id:
        :param node_type:
        :param edge_value:
        :param val:
        :param split_type:
        :param split_cond:
        :return:
        """
        node_id = len(self.model)  # id of the newly assigned node
        if not self.model:  # the tree is empty
            node_type = NodeType.root

        node = Node(node_id, node_type, parent_id, children=[], edge_value=edge_value, val=val, split_type=split_type,
                    split_cond=split_cond)
        self.model.append(node)

        # also add it as a child of the parent node
        if parent_id is not None:
            self.model[parent_id].append_child(node_id)

        return node_id

    def __id3(self, attrs, records, parent_id=None, value=None):
        """
        Function ID3 that returns a decision tree.

        :param attrs: Set of attributes
        :param records: Training set (list of record ids)
        :param parent_id: ID of parent node
        :param value: Value corresponding to the parent attribute, i.e., label of the edge on which we arrived to this node
        :return:
        """
        # empty training set or empty set of attributes => create leaf node with default class
        if not records or not attrs:
            self.__add_node(parent_id, node_type=NodeType.leaf, edge_value=value, val=self.default_class)
            return

        # if all records have the same target value => create leaf node with that target value
        same = all(self.data[idx][IDX_TARGET] == self.data[records[0]][IDX_TARGET] for idx in records)
        if same:
            target = self.data[records[0]][IDX_TARGET]
            self.__add_node(parent_id, node_type=NodeType.leaf, edge_value=value, val=target)
            return

        # find the attribute with the largest gain
        splitting = self.__find_best_attr(attrs, records)
        # add node
        node_id = self.__add_node(parent_id, edge_value=value, val=splitting.attr, split_type=splitting.split_type,
                                  split_cond=splitting.cond)
        # TODO call tree construction recursively for each split
        node = self.model[node_id]
        for n_id in node.children:
            self.__id3(attrs, records, node_id, node.val)
        return self.model
    def print_model(self, node_id=0, level=0):
        node = self.model[node_id]
        indent = "  " * level
        if node.type == NodeType.leaf:
            print(indent + str(node.edge_value) + " [Leaf node] class=" + node.val)
        else:
            cond = " <= " + str(node.split_cond) if ATTR[node.val].type == AttrType.num else " == ? "
            if node.type == NodeType.root:
                print("[Root node] '" + ATTR[node.val].label + "'" + cond)
            else:
                print(indent + str(node.edge_value) + " [Internal node] '" + ATTR[node.val].label + "'" + cond)
            # print tree for child notes recursively
            for n_id in node.children:
                self.print_model(n_id, level + 1)

    def build_model(self):
        self.__load_data()
        #print(list(range(len(self.data))))
        #print(list(range(len(self.data))))
        self.model = []  # holds the decision tree model, represented as a list of nodes
        # Get majority class
        #   Note: Counter returns a dictionary, most_common(x) returns a list with the x most common elements as
        #         (key, count) tuples; we need to take the first element of the list and the first element of the tuple
        self.default_class = Counter([x[IDX_TARGET] for x in self.data]).most_common(1)[0][0]
        self.__id3(set(range(len(ATTR) - 1)), list(range(len(self.data))))

    def apply_model(self, record):
        node = self.model[0]
        while node.type != NodeType.leaf:
            # TODO based on the value of the record's attribute that is tested in `node`,
            # set `node` to one of its child nodes until a leaf node is reached
            for n_id in node.children:
                node = self.model[n_id]
        return node.val

def main():
    dt = DT()
    print("Build model:")
    dt.build_model()
    dt.print_model()

    print("\nApply model:")
    print(dt.apply_model(['sunny', 85, 85, 'false']))
    print(dt.apply_model(['overcast', 75, 85, 'true']))
    print(dt.apply_model(['rain', 75, 85, 'false']))

if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Comment: Surely this is not right: `self.__id3(set(range(len(ATTR) - 1)), list(range(len(self.data))))`?

Comment: Why not? id3 is called with the attributes and training set/record ids

Comment: Because `records` is a list of `int` objects (which aren't subscriptable): `__id3(attrs, records: List[int], ...)` -> `__find_best_attr(attrs, records)` -> `split_categorical(records, ...)` -> `[x for x in records if x[attr_name] ...]`. What is `x` here?! (PS: in future, always include the *whole* traceback in your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you are right, records is a list of indexes to records, but I treated records as it was the value of the indexes. I made som changes to the function and it works now: 
def __entropy(self, records): n = Counter([self.data[x][4] for x in records]) return sum([(-freq / len(records)) * math.log(freq / len(records), 2) for freq in n.values()])#eksempel: